# Access denied when trying to delete a file in Temporary ASP.NET Files folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, permission-denied

I am unable to run a web application after a build in VS 2013. I get the following error:

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\Thelonius\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\vs\3874c594\43dbfd8b\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.dll' is
>   denied.

I tried to delete the DLL using Windows Explorer directly, but I was met with the following dialog:

> You require permission from the computer's administrator to make
>   changes to this file DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.dll

I found it odd since I was running as the administrator. When I tried to change the permissions from the Security Tab in Explorer, I got the following message:

> You must have Read permissions to view the properties of this object.

I am unable to change the ownership on the project. Is there a solution to this problem or should I just make another ASP.NET temporary file folder?  This is strange. If it helps, I am running Windows 10.

For what it's worth, Windows Handle utility claims that VS 2013 has the file open, but why can't it delete it? Also, if the file is open by Visual Studio 2012, shouldn't the error message say that the file is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To been able to clear the Temporary asp.net directory you need to :

1. Stop the IIS service (or just stop the web site that you wish to clear)
2. Close all visual studio programs (or only the web site that you work with)

Comment: I would adjust your answer to quit VS Studio as well.  See my edits. It would be nice to know how this happened.

Comment: @user148298 Its because vs builds on background asp.net project and creates the links and other informatiosn that needs to show you when you programming, like for example the class infomations about functions...